# Given overdetermined system $Ax=b$, how can we compute $c^T\hat{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

I have an overdetermined system

$$Ax=b$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ has full column rank and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let $\hat{x}$ denote the least squares solution.

If am given $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, how can I compute $\alpha = c^T \hat{x}$ without solving for $\hat{x}$ explicitly?

I am given the hint that if I consider $Z$ as a Householder matrix such that $Z^T c$ is a multiple of $I_n(:,n)$, it follows that $\alpha = (Z^Tc)^T \hat{y}$, where $\hat{y}$ is the least squares solution to $\|\tilde{A}y-b\|_2$, with $y=Z^Tx$ and $\tilde{A}=AZ$

In looking at $\alpha = (Z^Tc)^T$, I concluded (not sure if 100% correctly) that $\alpha$ is the product of 2-norm of $c$ and last element of $\hat{y}$:  i.e., $\alpha = \|c\|_2\cdot \hat{y}[n] \cdot \mbox{sign}(c[n])$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Indeed, if $Z^Tc=\beta e_n$ ($|\beta|=\|c\|_2$), then $\alpha=c^T\hat{x}=c^TZZ^T\hat{x}=\beta e_n^T\hat{y}$.

Comment: I see. I understand that this would avoid solving $\hat{x}$ explicitly by solving for $\hat{y}$ instead. But, is there a clear advantage of doing this (such as fewer flops)? It seems like we still have to find some least square solution ($\hat{y}$ intstead of $\hat{x}$).

Comment: I'm not sure where the advantage really is if there's any. It is true you do not need the full solution vector $\hat{y}$, just its last entry. So, e.g., if you solve for it using a QR factorization without pivoting, that is easily done (just need to invert the the last diagonal entry of $R$ and forget the rest of the back substitution). However, you still need to form $\bar{A}$ which IMHO is more expensive that the full solve with $R$ at least in terms of flops, especially when $m\gg n$.

Comment: If computing $c^Tx$ is simple, you could take $c = e_i$ to get the $i^{th}$ component of $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "without solving for $\hat{x}$ explicitly"? Is it that you want to avoid calculating $\left(A^{\top}A\right)^{-1}$?

Comment: By "explicitly" I meant a proposed method shouldn't calculate every entry of $\hat{x}$. I think the main idea of this problem was to recognize that we don't need to solve for the full $\hat{y}$. I believe the reasoning Pavel described is correct. We still have to form $\tilde{A}$ but we just calculate the last element of $\hat{y}$.